# Will a US entry denial affect a Canada visa application?

Tags: canada, visa-refusals, study, deportation

I traveled to the USA in 2016 on a student visa. However, I was deported and banned for five years because my documents were incorrect, and some of them were fake (related to financial status). I was wrongly guided by the consultancy I used.

Now I am planning to apply for Canada (PR) Express Entry, using correct and original documents. Will I be refused again?

*Clarification (per OP's deleted answer): refused entry upon arrival at the border, which resulted expedited removal and the 5-year ban.*

Comment: Very likely. USA and Canada share such info and with fraudulent documents, your chances are slim.

Comment: Deported no one knows, but your previous record will be in Canadian visa officer's hands while making a decision.

Comment: Were you refused entry when you arrived in the US? This is different than deportation (although it can have a similar impact on future visa applications).

Comment: A friend was removed from the USA for overstaying. He is now a Canadian citizen.

Comment: @greatone Unfortunately there is a big difference between 'overstay' and 'used fraudulent documents'

Comment: @DJClayworth if the fraudulent documents were material to the application to enter, the OP would have received a lifetime ban. There must be some other reason for the 5 year ban.

Comment: @greatone, That's not right. Lifetime bans are given only for aggravated felonies or for certain cases of entering illegally after a prior removal. A 5 year ban is probably right for a port-of-entry deportation, 10 years if a judge orders the removal.

Comment: @Dennis 212(a)(6)(C)(i) Material Misrepresentation / Fraud is a lifetime ban. (
(i) In general.-Any alien who, by fraud or willfully misrepresenting a 
 material fact, seeks to procure (or has sought to procure or has procured) a 
 visa, other documentation, or admission into the United States or other benefit 
 provided under this Act is inadmissible.) https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-29/0-0-0-2006.html

Comment: Please I'll like to know what the end result to your express entry application was. I am currently in the same situation as I have a lifetime ban from USA over 11 years ago for misrepresentation and now I want to migrate legally to Canada. I will really appreciate your reply.

Comment: I was wondering if you finally got your Canadian PR.

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, the US and Canada explicitly share information regarding visa refusals, involuntary removals (deportations) etc. with each other, based on a [bilateral treaty](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/transparency/access-information-privacy/privacy-impact-assessment/us-canada-information-sharing-treaty.html) to that effect.

However, Canada is an independent jurisdiction from the US, and will make a decision on your application based on their own criteria. It's very unlikely that Canada will automatically reject your application simply because you have been denied entry to, or removed from, the US at an earlier time. However, you can certainly expect to face additional scrutiny, which could possibly result in a refusal, if your documents are not watertight.

In summary, your history with US immigration will almost certainly affect your Canadian application to some extent, but the exact degree to which it does so will depend on the strength of your fresh application, as well as the discretion of Canadian visa officers.